# Explanation of a decorator class in python

Tags: python, properties, decorator

While reading up about some python module I encountered this decorator class:

```
# this decorator lets me use methods as both static and instance methods
class omnimethod(object):
        def __init__(self, func):
                self.func = func

        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
                return functools.partial(self.func, instance)
```

What I know about decorators, is that the can *extend* functionality (e.g. for a function). Could someone be so kind and explain to me **why** the class above is useful and **how it exactly works**?

It is used in the code this way:

```
@omnimethod:
def some_function(...):
    pass
```

Another question:

```
I encountered this piece of code in the same file:

@property
def some_other_function(...):
    pass
```

`@property` is not defined anywhere in the file. Is this some standard decorator? If yes, what does it do? Google couldn't help me on this case.

By the way, here is the source where I found the code: http://code.xster.net/pygeocoder/src/c9460febdbd1/pygeocoder.py

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators#What_is_a_Decorator

Comment: If you couldn't find out what `property` is, your Google-fu needs work: search for "python property" and you quickly get to things like http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property. And from there to things like http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-decorator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that omnimethod is very clever.  It uses some very subtle tricks to do it's job.  Let's start at the beginning.

You probably already know that [decorator syntax](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) is just sugar for function application,  ie:

```
@somedecorator
def somefunc(...):
    pass

# is the same thing as    

def somefunc(...):
    pass
somefunc = somedecorator(somefunc)
```

so `somefunc` is actually an `omnimethod` instance, not the function that had been defined.  what's interesting about this is that `omnimethod` also implements the [`descriptor` interface.](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)  If a class attribute defines a `__get__` method, then whenever that attribute is mentioned, the interpreter instead calls `__get__` on that object, and returns that instead of returning the attribute itself.

the `__get__` method is always called with instance as first argument, and the class of that instance as second argument.  If the attribute was actually looked up from the class itself, then instance will be `None`.

The last bit of trickery is [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which is the python way of function [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).  when you use `partial`, you pass it a function and some arguments, and it returns a new function, that when called, will call the original function with the original arguments in addition to whichever arguments you passed in later.  `omnimethod` uses this technique to populate the `self` parameter to the function it wraps.

Here's what that looks like.  a [regular method](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) can be called when you read it from an instance but you can't use it from the class itself.   you get an unbound TypeError

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def bar(self, baz):
...         print self, baz
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar('apples')
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fe81ab52f90> apples
>>> Foo.bar('quux')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with 
Foo instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
>>> Foo.bar(None, 'quux')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with
Foo instance as first argument (got NoneType instance instead)
>>>
```

Python provides a bultin decorator [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) (and also `staticmethod`, but nevermind that), that will allow you to use it at the class level, but it never gets to see the instance.  it *always* recieves the class as it's first argument.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def bar(cls, baz):
...         print cls, baz
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> Foo.bar('abc')
<class '__main__.Foo'> abc
>>> f.bar('def')
<class '__main__.Foo'> def
>>>
```

By it's bit of cleverness, `omnimethod` gives you a little bit of both.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @omnimethod
...     def bar(self, baz):
...         print self, baz
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> Foo.bar('bananas')
None bananas    
>>> f.bar('apples')
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fe81ab52f90> apples
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

omnimethod does what it says in the comment; it will let you call some_function as either a 'static function' on a class or as a function on an instance of the class. @property is a standard decorator (see the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)) that exposes a function in a way that makes it look like a simple instance variable.

```
class B:
  @omnimethod
  def test(self):
    print 1

  @property
  def prop(self):
    return 2

>>> b = B()
>>> b.test()
1
>>> B.test()
1
>>> b.prop
2
```